# Rails using javascript to replace html

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a create.js.erb file that has to perform two actions:
a) replace the contents of a div with a html partial
b) replace the contents of a div with a partial containing erb

The first works perfectly however when I add the second command it all stops.

My create.js.erb file is a follows:

```
$("#my_groups").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/my_groups')) %>");
$("#membership_options").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('membership_options')) %>");
```

The "membership_options" partial contains a single rails html helper command being:

"<%= membership_options %>"

Error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial
>   memberships/_membership_options, application/_membership_options with
>   {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[],
>   :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
>   Searched in:   * "/home/mchenry/Documents/star/app/views" ):
>       1: $("#my_groups").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/my_groups')) %>");
>       2: $("#membership_options").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('membership_options')) %>");
>   app/views/memberships/create.js.erb:2:in
>   `_app_views_memberships_create_js_erb___3983809285480123111_70283432617520'   app/controllers/memberships_controller.rb:7:in`create'

Comment: what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Can you post logs from terminal? what do you see in browsers console?

Comment: what if you give the whole path to the membership options (from the views folder), like you do with `shared/my_groups`

Comment: In which directory you have membership_options partial? You need to use full path in render option to get rid of that error

Comment: the error says there is no partial called 'membership_options`, you should add / rename the file

Comment: I had the partial in the wrong folder with the incorrect path.